# QuickAction and a way to hide an item

Tags: android, android-menu, quickaction

I'm using the code from [here](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/) to create a quickaction.

I'm coding a game and I want to use quickaction function as menu. So, when the user click on "Pause" I want to remove or disable to click "Reset" button..

or if you have a better idea than mine, I can change, but I have no space on screen while gaming and because of that I want to use menu button, then on screen I'll use just one button and its enough for me.

Of course with this menu I'm going to remove some buttons too.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new instance of `QuickAction` when you click the button, but don't include the 'Reset' button this time.